# excel pivot table maximum amount of data

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

The VBA code I wrote to select all active cells within my range works perfectly for a small amount of data. But when I have 80.000 rows I recieve an error for creating my Pivot Table.
The data I use is to calculate an average for a few temperatures. Besides average i need to calculate, stdev, var, amount, min and max

Pivot table I want to create:
[image: 1]

When i select more than 80.000 it creates the error code "undefined expression in context"

vba code:
[image: 2]

So my question is, is there a maximum amount to create a pivot table?
And if there is, is there a way to solve this problem?

```
Sub Draaitabel()
Sheets("Draaitabellen").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Dim newRange As Range
Sheets("Doorvoeren").Select
Range("B3:D3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set newRange = Selection

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        newRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Draaitabellen!R3C1", TableName:="Draaitabel1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Draaitabellen").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Steekproef")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Temperatuur"), "Som van Temperatuur", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Som van Temperatuur")
        .Caption = "Aantal van Temperatuur"
        .Function = xlCount
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Temperatuur"), "Som van Temperatuur", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Som van Temperatuur")
        .Caption = "Gemiddelde van Temperatuur"
        .Function = xlAverage
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Temperatuur"), "Som van Temperatuur", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Som van Temperatuur")
        .Caption = "Stdev van Temperatuur"
        .Function = xlStDev
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Temperatuur"), "Som van Temperatuur", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Som van Temperatuur")
        .Caption = "Var van Temperatuur"
        .Function = xlVar
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Temperatuur"), "Som van Temperatuur", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Som van Temperatuur")
        .Caption = "Min van Temperatuur"
        .Function = xlMin
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Temperatuur"), "Som van Temperatuur", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Som van Temperatuur")
        .Caption = "Max van Temperatuur"
        .Function = xlMax
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Tijd"), "Som van Tijd", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotFields("Som van Tijd")
        .Caption = "Min van Tijd"
        .Function = xlMin
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please embed the code and make it highlighted (code format button).

Comment: I can't open the link you have posted. Please write the code here. Maybe you have to increase the version of pivot. You should have something like "Version:=xlPivotTableVersion..."

Comment: added code like you prefered

Comment: Microsoft says there is a limit in the number of items on the report, but the source data shouldn't matter, as long as your computer's memory can handle it. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmpivottable